# How to initialize hash so I can use it in a method?

Tags: ruby, hash

Oddly enough I coldn't find any information for that anywhere on the internet.

I have a class method which is supposed to add something to a hash. For example:

```
def add_file(name, file)
  @files[name] = file
end
```

If I initialize the hash with `@files = Hash.new` in the same method it would make a whole new hash every time I try to add something to it rather than add things to it. But when I move the initialization out of the method in the class body itself it comes up with an error:

```
in 'add_file': undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

So how do I initialize the hash so that I can use it in another method later.

**Keep the explanation simple, please, I'm new. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *not* always check for the presence of the hash in the `add`/etc methods.

This requires *always* checking for the hash in anything that expects it.

If the class is meant as a wrapper for a file store it only makes sense to create it on instantiation, e.g.,

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize
    @files = {}
  end

  def add_file(name, file)
    # Etc.
  end
end
```

---

It fails with hash creation in the class body because that's at the *class*, not *instance*, level, e.g.,

```
class NotWhatYouExpect
  @foo = "bar"
end
```

`@foo` is a *class* instance variable; it belongs to the *class* `NotWhatYouExpect` rather than *instances* of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    def add_file(name, file)
      @files || = {} #Checking if hash is initialized. If not initializing
      @files[name] = file #adding element
      @files #returning hash
    end
```

This will add a new key-val pair and return the complete hash.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an instance method, not a class method.  The difference is it's a method that can be called on a particular instance of a class.

In any case, you can do

```
def add_file(name, file)
  @files ||= {}
  @files[name] = file
end
```

That will initialize @files to an empty hash unless the instance variable is present (and not false)

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an instance member (a variable beginning with `@`) inside the class declaration (not inside a method) the member is initialized as a member of the *class*, not its instances.

To initialize a member for each instance, you need to do it inside the initialize method:

```
class MyTest

  @class_hash = Hash.new

  def initialize()
    @instance_hash = Hash.new
  end

  def class_hash
    @class_hash
  end

  def instance_hash
    @instance_hash
  end

  def self.class_hash
    @class_hash
  end
end

puts MyTest.new.class_hash
# => nil
puts MyTest.new.instance_hash
# => {}
puts MyTest.class_hash
# => {}
```